# Visual Studio 2019 - Fast Find? (CTRL-T) like resharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I've recently disabled ReSharper because of performance reasons, it has been horrid in terms of slowing down my workflow.

One feature I used all the time was CTRL-T to rapidly find a file.  I can do CTR-; or search in the Solution Explorer but it really isn't the same.

Is there some other hot key or extension I can install to get the ReSharper CTR-T search similar feature?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Visual Studio 2019 / 2022 has a relative similar feature 'Edit.GoToAll' it even has the same default key binding Ctrl+T see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019):
[default keyboard binding of Edit.GoToAll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgCBU.png)

Looks like the keyboard binding just got lost e.g. by uninstalling ReSharper.